# ValueStateText for sap.m.Input

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to make the value state text for an sap.m.input to stay visible after the control has lost focus?

Currently, it is showing up while the control has focus and hides itself when it looses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found

[InputBase/openValueStateMessage](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/openValueStateMessage)

so basicly

```
this.byId("input-control-id").openValueStateMessage();
```

should work, but it is a protected method and Sap says: "Don't use private and protected methods or properties of UI5."